# Split a text into multiple sentences in bash

Tags: bash, split

I would like to split text into sentences. Sentence ends with a dot and followed by whitespace character.

Comment: not my area of knowledge, but maybe this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash

Comment: OT: Some might say that that definition of a sentence isn't very universal! E.g. Mr. Doe, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using tr/sed:

```
tr '\n' ' ' <  input | sed -e 's/[.] \s*/. \n/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

This will print each separate sentence on a new line.

```
awk  'BEGIN{RS="\\. "}1' file
```